# Drop Frame is missing in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I downloaded the intellij community edition.
Is DropToFrame is available only in Ultimate Edition?

Any other plugin add this to intellij community edition

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The `Drop Frame` was renamed to `Reset Frame` and now is located to the left of the frame name in Frames view (curved arrow icon on the screenshot)

[image]

You may add it manually in `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars - Debug Tool Window Top Toolbar`:

[image]

Comment: I don't see an option in the frames. It goes the 1st execution line or restart. I have 50 break points. I am in 18th break point. The drop to frame will goes to 17th...Can you please help with the steps clearly.

Comment: There is no Reset Frame option in the tool bar as well. Are you sure you are referring to Intellij Community Edition ?

Comment: Please make sure you're using the latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download . Probably the option is missing because you have only one frame available. Please attach a screenshot showing debugger tool window.

Comment: Kelpikov - It is not available and am using Build #IC-222.3739.54, built on August 16, 2022

Comment: It is not avaialble even in the recent build 2022.2.2 Community Edition. @Egor Kilepikov - are you sure whether you have verified in the community edition. please attach the screenshot of the about page in your intellij

Comment: Did you get a chance to go through the above?

Comment: In second screenshot, there is + option. Use this option then choose debugger Actions where you will see the icon reset Frame, choose and apply that.